# How can I use pointers passed as arguments to a C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, pointers, console-application

How can I use pointers passed as arguments to a C# Console Application?
I got roundly thrummed for this question and my question closed, for my brevity perhaps.  Maybe I'm asking the wrong question, so I will give the scenario I'm up against.

I have a legacy application, which I do not have the ability to edit.  The legacy application has the ability to invoke an exe, at which time it passes pointers to external datalists (their language, not mine).

I have a C# Console Application, when the legacy app invokes the C# Console Application, the argument received is a single string.  Something of the sort of

```
c4bds.WWW000054,1,c4bds.WWW000054,60025
```

I recognize part of this string as values describing the workstation in the legacy system.  But none of the rest of it makes any sense to me.

In a C++ console app, the main can be structured such as this...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

The application I must write to be called by the legacy application, will be in .NET.
Typically in .NET references are used instead of pointers.

A main in C# console application typically looks like this...

```
int main(string[] args)
```

Thus my question. How can I interpret the values of the arguments sent by the calling application?  Or otherwise, how can I accomplish the needed functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments passed to your console application aren't pointers (I don't see how this could be since two different processes can't access each others memory, in theory).

You'll have to guess what those values mean since I don't know your legacy application (it could be `<workstation>.<filename or ressource name>,<list index>`), but I can tell you how to read arguments in a .Net console application.

It actually works the same as in C++ (except you don't have the variable `argc`, since you can get the number of arguments using `args.Length`).

All your arguments are in the array `args`, the first being the program name.

For example, if you call a .Net program called `MyProg.exe` like that:

```
MyProg.exe argument1 argument2
```

you'll have

```
args[0] = "MyProg.exe"
args[1] = "argument1"
args[2] = "argument2"
```

Comment: And, of course, you can obtain the old C++ - style parameter `argc` as `argv.Length`

Comment: yep, should have said that when I talked about the number of arguments, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I'm clear on how to parse arguments in .NET.  I'm just not clear on what the values are I'm receiving.  It makes no sense to me.  Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: if you can post the specifications of the parameters sent by your legacy app it would be easier to help you, but with the information you gave it's hard to guess... Also it wouldn't change the fact that these aren't pointers, at best a memory address but I doubt it

Comment: the arguments could be `<workstation>.<filename>,<list index>` but that's just a guess